# Find the most common pairs in a Dataframe of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns `ID, Product`. For example,

```
ID  Product
1   ['a','b']
2   ['a','b','e']
3   ['c','d']
4   ['a','b','c','d']
```

`Product` is a field of lists where each list contains the products that a person has. For example, a person with `ID` 1 has the products `a` and `b`. I need to find the most popular/common product pairs. In this example, products `[a,b]` is the most popular. It has to be the most common product pairs since no person can have 1 product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to acquire all such combinations of pairs possible and convert the resulting series to it's list representation that needs to be fed to a dataframe constructor later.

2) Stack the `DF` and take respective [`Series.value_counts()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Grab the index with the highest count using [`Series.idxmax()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html).

---

```
import itertools

comb = lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 2))
L = df['Product'].map(comb).tolist()
pd.DataFrame(L).stack().value_counts(sort=False).idxmax()
Out[21]:
('a', 'b')
```

---

***Edit:*** (based on comment stating a new requirement)

```
a, cnt = np.unique(df.Product.values, return_counts=True)
a[cnt==cnt.max()]
array([['a', 'b', 'e']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I need it to look for more than 2 Products groups. Should the data set change to this.

`ID  Product
1   ['a','b','e']
2   ['a','b','e']
3   ['c','d']
4   ['a','b','c','d']`

It must find `['a','b','e']` as the most popular

Comment: Well, that was nowhere mentioned in your post. You kept stressing the word "pairs", so I assumed you are grouping according to their pairwise combinations and taking the pair having the maximum count. What would the new criterion be?

Comment: I apologize, it needn't be a pairwise comparison. Basically, it must just be a group of product that majority of people have selected. It other words it can be 3,4,5 etc.

Comment: I think you want to know the association between the products. For this you can use the Apriori algorithm or other Association rule learning algorithms.

Comment: @JavaBeginner: Can you maybe edit your post with a clear and simple explanation as to what you want to achieve really? Also, I've updated my post to accommodate for the newly included dataset.

Comment: Great! Though I would sort each product list, i.e. `itertools.combinations(sorted(x), 2)` to make sure that there is no duplicates, e.g. `('a', 'b')` and `('b', 'a')` are the same pairs if order does not matter.